# Is the Haar measure of a product of finite measure and compact, finite?

Tags: measure-theory, topological-groups

Let $G$ be a locally compact group with Haar measure $ \mu $, $K \subset G$ a compact subset and $ F \subset G $ any subset of finite Haar measure $\mu (F) < \infty $.

Is the Haar measure of the product $ \mu(KF) $ finite as well?

I know that the compactness of $K$ implies that $\mu(K)<\infty$, and that the above would be true if F was compact (since then $ KF$ would be compact as well).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $G:=\Bbb R$ (additive group) with Lebesgue measure, $K:=[0,1]$ and $F:=\Bbb Z$. Then $$KF=\{x+y,x\in [0,1],y\in\Bbb Z\}=\Bbb R$$
which has infinite measure.

Comment: Thank you, you are right and I missed this rather simple example.

Comment: In fact, when I said that $F$ has finite Haar measure, I was thinking about a set that is a fundamental domain for some lattice $\Gamma$ in $G$. Then $F$ is "localized" in some sense, even if it is not compact. So perhaps I can reformulate the question, with the additional assumption that $F$ is indeed a fundamental domain for a lattice $\Gamma$ in $G$ ?